# Need client side Web application to access local application I wrote

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vbscript, smartcard

The overall goal is I need to have a web based time clock system that access the ID from an HID prox card.    I written the web application side in C# ASPX .net Framework 4 and a local application in C# .net Framework 4 to access the HID Omnikey 5325 USB card reader to get the ID from the prox card.   I just now need to get that information over to the web application via the client.  Trying to figure how to get the two to talk to each other.   Creating a shared file is not an option.

The web Client and Prox card application are running on the same computer.

End User Experience:

User walk up to touch screen display and card reader.
Taps card.
Choose Clock In or Clock out.
Walks away.

Application needs to be web based as the overhead of distribution is to big for the scale I am working with, and the manpower I have.

Any Ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You just need an Service at server side, it can be an MVC Controller if you have ASP.net MVC on Server side or a WCF Service. and call that service from your C# application.

Comment: A WCF Service is going to be your best bet since the web application and client are both in C#.

Comment: I think the author is saying that he needs his web client to be able to access his C# app that reads the HID card, which is also running on the client machine.  But I do think the solution would be the same; You could open a self-hosted WCF service in the C# application on the client that reads the HID card, and have the web client call it at `localhost` through Javascript (AJAX style). Then the web client can send that back to its server.

Comment: How does the web client know when to call the WCF service.  (How does it know when the service has data to send?)  I am not familar with WCF being able to raise events on the web client side.